# Handling large mp3 files(>200mb) to cut them into small pieces?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried pydub's AudioSegment but it can only load small files. For large files my cpu runs at max and just stops after a couple minutes by killing the process.

I don't have any code written yet. The file is an mp3 audiobook that was downloaded from piratebay. Duration is 8 hours and filesize around 300mb. I want to cut the file into multiple files 30-60 mins each so that I can sync them with apple music(Doesn't allow large files).

Pydub doesnt't even load it so I haven't gone any further.

There are softwares to achieve this but I'm trying to do it with python.

Comment: in shoirt, to cut up audio files you use **ffmpeg**.  I don't really understand your milieu but, in general, that's how you chop up audio and process audio generally

Comment: Simply google "python library for ffmpeg" to get the wrapper library you'll need.